# View [index] not found in Laravel 5.4 Production

Tags: php, laravel

I'm having issues with a laravel 5.4 app deployed on shared hosting. I'm getting the error

> (1/1) InvalidArgumentException
>   View [index] not found.
>
> in FileViewFinder.php (line 137)
>   at FileViewFinder->findInPaths('index', array('D:\wamp64\www\oagc\resources\views'))
>   in FileViewFinder.php (line 79)

This is what I have done so far

1. Clear routes in development server (my laptop)
   [image]
   [image]
2. Moved all folders and files in my app root folder except public folder to /home/tmworkxc/oagc
   [image]
3. Moved all folders and files in app public folder to public_html/oagconsult.ng folder
   [image]
4. Edited public_html/oagconsult.ng/index.php

   `require __DIR__.'/../../oagc/bootstrap/autoload.php';`

   `$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../../oagc/bootstrap/app.php';`

Did I miss anything that is causing the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the issue running the command `php artisan config:clear`. I have no idea why `php artisan config:cache` did not work but i'll update my answer when i find out the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Closures cannot be serialized, therefore your route which uses a closure (anonymous function) cannot be cached.

Check this code to see my point: https://3v4l.org/BcVJi

```
$x = function(){return 'whatever';};
serialize($x);
```

Comment: I am not using api routes, my routes are in web.php file

Comment: one of your routes use ` function(){//blah}`

Answer (score 0):

Just delete all files in the bootstrap/cache folder of the server. Now the server will not use the cache of the localhost.